# Is there any good practice alternative to global variable in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[image]
It's an address register, that I use javascript to dynamically populate a HTML table with the inputs content.
I don't want it to insert into the database until she had filled as many addresses as she want, so it's basically adding the input values to the table.
[image]
The problem is, I need to pass these values as an array of addresses, to insert them on my database.
I don't think parsing the table to get data would be efficient or a good approach, would global variable be a bad thing in this case?
If you have any better ideas to solve this, please share.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery you could attach a data model to the table using the http://api.jquery.com/data/ function.

Comment: How about `list<Address>` and every time she puts in a new address you push the Address object to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a JSON-based representation of your dataset and update it along with your DOM table. Then you send the JSON object to the server via AJAX.

This is not really a "global variable" issue.

There are plenty of frameworks to help you with this if you don't want to roll-your-own: Backbone, Angular, Ember, etc.